# If $l(B,A)$ is a prime ideal then $B$ is maximal in $A$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $B\subset A$ be commutative rings with identity. Furthermore $B$ is a domain. We are given the set $$l(B,A) = \{ b\in B\setminus \{0\}: B[b^{-1}] = A[b^{-1}]\} \cup \{0\},$$ where $B[b^{-1}]$ means the $B$-algebra generated by $b^{-1}$. It can be proved that $l(B,A)$ is an ideal. The problem is:

> Show that if $l(B,A)$ is a prime ideal then $B$ is maximal in $A$.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Dear user, What do you mean by maximal?  With the obvious interpretation (that $B$ is a maximal proper subring of $A$) this is false as written.  E.g. if $B = \mathbb C$ and $A = \mathbb C[x]$, then $l(B,A) = 0,$ which is prime, but there are many rings intermediate between $A$ and $B$, e.g. $\mathbb C[x^2]$.  Note that there is nothing special about the choice of $\mathbb C$; it could be any field, or even any integral domain.  Did you intend to assume something more about the situation; e.g. that $A$ is finite over $B$, or even that $A$ is contained in the fraction field of $B$?  Regards,

Comment: $l(B,A)$ is an ideal of $B$. But Matt is correct. The problem is wrong. There must have been a typo where I read it. It is true that $B$ maximal in $A$ implies that $l$ is prime but it is not a necessary and sufficient condition as it said where I read it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give this an answer: it seems that the problem was incorrectly stated in the source.  As written the claim is not true.  E.g. if $B= \mathbb C$ and $A=\mathbb C[x]$, then l(B,A)=0, which is prime, but there are many rings intermediate between A and B, e.g. $\mathbb C[x^2]$. Note that there is nothing special about the choice of $\mathbb C$; it could be any field, or even any integral domain.  Another counterexample is given by $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$.